# rsync: mkstemp "<filename>" failed: Function not implemented (38)

Tags: rsync, fat32, exfat

When trying to to an `rsync` transfer, I get the following error:

`rsync: mkstemp "<filename>" failed: Function not implemented (38)`

`rsync` doesn't actually transfer the files it lists with --progress: subsequent `rsync`s start from the beginning again.

The target filesystem is FAT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mkstemp` makes a temporary file and sets its permissions to `0600`. If the underlying filesystem (eg FAT) doesn't support permissions, this will fail.

So, append the flag:

```
--no-perms
```

Given that your target filesystem doesn't support owner and group attributes either, you'll probably want:

```
--no-perms --no-owner --no-group
```

or, shorter:

```
--no-p --no-o --no-g
```

Comment: I don't think those options are available in my rsync version 2.6.9

Comment: @codepringle get a new statically-compiled version [here](https://github.com/JBBgameich/rsync-static/).